# How to anchor a dialog to a button in listview qt qml

Tags: qt, listview, scroll, qml

I have a row for a listview delegate with buttons on it. On click of a button, i need a dialog to open just below that button. I tried mapToItem property and partially succeeded but this listview is scrollable and on scrolling the dialog stays in its initial position. Unsure of how to get it working. Also, new to posting questions. Kindly ignore if I am being vague and help me out.

The dialog i want to open is placed outside of this delegate. I have provided a short outline of my code.

```
Listview{
delegate: Row{
  Button1{
   }
  Button2{
   id: button2Id
   onCheckedChanged{
    var coords = button2Id.mapToItem(null,0,0)
    dialogId.x = coords.x
    dialogId.y= coords.y 
    dialogId.visible = true
    }
  }
 }
}

//dialog rect outside of my listview
Rectangle{
id: dialogId
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add the dialog to the highlight item of the list. I have modified your example a little so that I could test it. I encapsulated your `Rectangle` in an `Item` because `ListView` controls the size and position of the root object of the highlight. The `Rectangle` then just has to be anchored to the bottom of that `Item`.

```
    ListView {
        id: lv
        width: 200
        height: parent.height
        model: 50
        spacing: 1
        currentIndex: -1
        delegate: Row {
            spacing: 1
            height: 40
            Button {
                text: index
            }
            Button {
                id: button2Id
                text: ">"
                onClicked: {
                    lv.currentIndex = index;
                }
            }
        }

        highlight: Item {  // ListView controls the size/pos of this Item
            z: 1

            Rectangle {
                id: dialogId
                anchors.top: parent.bottom  // Anchor to bottom of parent
                width: 200
                height: 100
                color: "red"
            }
        }
    }
```

**UPDATE:**

Here is a way to keep the dialog directly under the button without calculating margins. I put it in a `Loader` so that each item in the list doesn't always carry the whole dialog around with it. It might make a performance difference.

The ugly part of this solution is the z-ordering. Each item in the list is drawn after the one that comes sequentially before it. (I'm not actually sure if that's even guaranteed.) That means the dialog gets drawn underneath any item that comes after it in the list. I was able to get around that by changing the `z` value of each item in the list to be less than the item before it.

```
ListView {
    id: lv
    width: 200
    height: parent.height
    model: 50
    spacing: 1
    currentIndex: -1
    delegate: Row {
        z: lv.count - index // <<- z-value fix
        spacing: 1
        height: 40
        Button {
            text: index
        }
        Button {
            id: button2Id
            text: ">"
            onClicked: {
                lv.currentIndex = index;
            }

            Loader {
                anchors.top: parent.bottom
                asynchronous: true
                sourceComponent: (index === lv.currentIndex) ? dialogComp : null
            }
        }
    }
}

Component {
    id: dialogComp
    Rectangle {
        id: dialogId
        width: 200
        height: 100
        color: "red"
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. It worked! Just want to know if there are any ways to position the dialog directly below button rather than using margins?

Comment: You can only anchor an object to its immediate parent or its siblings. So you could theoretically make the dialog a child or sibling of your button, but I wouldn't recommend it. That would mean every item in your list would have an instance of the dialog.

Comment: I guess that could be improved with a `Loader`. I'll make an update showing how it can be done.

Comment: I've been trying to make the dialog visible on click of the button. In addition to your code, I added Button2{ onClicked{ dialogId.visible = true } } and have set visible: false for dialogId. However , even on defining an alias, i am getting property not defined error. Why is this so?

Comment: My code already shows the dialog when you click the button. I'm not sure what you're missing.

Comment: The code you provided is initially showing the open dialog even without clicking the button.

Comment: Not in my testing. Setting `currentIndex: -1` is intended to prevent that.

Comment: I was facing that issue. Setting currentIndex: -1 in Component.onCompleted{} worked.